# SSMS 2017 Changing font size

Tags: ssms, ssms-2017

I'm using SSMS 2017 and want to make my font larger in the query window.
When I go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors** > and then change the size of my font and press Ok, nothing changes.  The size doesn't get affected in the open query window nor in a new query window.

Comment: What have you selected in the "Show settings for:" dropdownlist?

Comment: @JDoe, open up and focus a new query window, enter some text, then hold `CTRL` while scrolling up and down—that's an alternative way of adjusting the font size.

Comment: @miqid, thx for the workaround, the zoom function does work and gets the job done.  Seems like the font size change isn't working though.

Comment: @AarónBC, I have [All Text Tool Windows] selected

Comment: @JDoe Did you find any fix or workaround?

Comment: Changes to the actual font don't work either

Answer (score 8):

This is working in [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) v18.4.

1. In the menu click on `Tools` (1) and then on `Options`
2. The `Options` (2) dialogue opens
3. In  `Options` select `Fonts and colors` (3)
4. From ´Show settings for´ select `Grid Results` (4)
5. Change the font size (5)
6. Restart SSMS (6)

#### Screenshot

[image]

In OP's case I think you did not restart your ssms.

Also, as in arrow 4 you will need to know what settings you want to change in order for it to work as expect.

It should be very much the same for your ssms version.

Done.

Comment: And there is **Text Results** option for Messages window.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a mouse wheel, use the Ctrl key and two fingers on the touchpad: a pinching motion to enlarge/reduce the font in the Query Tab.

Comment: This works in the query tab but AFAIK not for the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be related to an early release.  I am using SSMS 17.4 and following your patch causes the query window font to change as soon as click 'ok'  the changes persist in a new query window and when I close and re-open SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using SSMS 2017 and also needed to increase the font size. To change the font size in your query window, make sure 'Text Editor' is chosen in the drop-down for 'Show settings for:' when you select Environment>Fonts and Colors. That will affect your query window font size once you select 'OK'. 
I'm not sure why the drop-down '[All Text Tool Windows]' doesn't affect the font size but I found that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you requested regarding font in window, which will be opened when you select **New Query** from database object (e.g. AutoLot), You can change size in  `Environment/Fonts and Colors/Text Editor`
[image: see picture]

Answer (score -1):

You must go to Environment font select a new font and size

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.